# no easy way to merge a git mv?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-submodules, git-commit

I have two repo:

App and Libs. Libs is a sub-module of App, so all my libs are like path: App/Libs/lib1 App/Libs/lib2 and so on. I had a library like App/libX and I did:

```
cd App
git mv libX ../Libs/
```

I then did a commit in Libs, and another in App (to update the submodule). Everything seems working in this feature branch- let's call it: ft_branch.

I then wanted to merge these edits in my dev branch, I went in the dev branch of Libs and merged ft_branch into dev. No problem so far. I then went into App and tried a merge of ft_branch into dev, but now I have this error:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): Libs deleted in ft_branch and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of Libs left in tree at Libs~HEAD.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried fixing the conflicts?

Comment: I basically git rm all the App/libX and now it seems ok.. but I've basically lost all history

Comment: Lost the history? What do you mean?

Comment: there is just a Libs/appX add without all the previous history of appX in the other repo

Comment: git mv doesn’t apply across repos

Comment: yep.. they must create some way to do that.. it would be awesome..

Comment: You know git doesn’t save history of individual files? If you transfer the history you get all the files in the repo.

Comment: yep, not the best thing